# Make a Media Player to list out in a player chooser dialog

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a Media Player application.I want my application to list out in a chooser dialog opens when user select any media file.How can I make my application to list out in a chooser dialog like image below :[image]

I have googled a lot but not found any related articles.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intent-filter` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Example.

```
<!-- Main activity -->
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.HomeActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- Now playing -->
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.AudioPlayerActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/playlist" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/albums" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/artists" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.andrew.apollo.AUDIO_PLAYER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/audio"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I select audio file to play directly from Mail.Can you please provide information to also play audio file from Mail?

Comment: Of course this will not work until you modify it. I suggest you first learn about `intent-filter` then checkout how apollow music player using them. https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo/blob/cm-11.0/AndroidManifest.xml